# Insert data into table in SQL Server from XML

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have `xml` like below. I want to insert in a table and I am expecting to insert 2 records, but it is inserting only one record.

Sample XML:

```
<xmlSubmitTime>
  <submitTime>
    <TaskDate>2016-08-29</TaskDate>
    <Project>
      <ProjectId>9</ProjectId>
      <Task>
        <TaskId>5</TaskId>
        <SubTask>
          <SubTaskId>4</SubTaskId>
          <Hours>2</Hours>
          <Comment>sample string 4</Comment>
        </SubTask>
        <SubTask>
          <SubTaskId>5</SubTaskId>
          <Hours>6</Hours>
          <Comment>sample string 4</Comment>
        </SubTask>
      </Task>
    </Project>
  </submitTime>
</xmlSubmitTime>
```

This is my insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO Sample
    SELECT
        submitTime.value('(Project/ProjectId/text())[1]', 'int') ,
        submitTime.value('(Project/Task/TaskId/text())[1]', 'int'),
        submitTime.value('(Project/Task/SubTask/SubTaskId/text())[1]', 'int'),
        submitTime.value('(TaskDate/text())[1]', 'date'),
        submitTime.value('(Project/Task/SubTask/Hours/text())[1]', 'int'),  
        0,
        submitTime.value('(Project/Task/SubTask/Comment/text())[1]', 'varchar(20)'),    
    FROM
        @SaveTimeDate.nodes('/xmlSubmitTime/submitTime') AS TEMPTABLE(submitTime)
```

Expected output is:

```
ProjectID  TaskId SubtaskId Hours
----------------------------------
9           5        4        2
9           5        5        6
```

Actual output is:

```
ProjectID  TaskId SubtaskId Hours
---------------------------------
 9           5        4        2
```

Comment: You have invalid xml structure. I think, for each subtask, you must taskID tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a second call to `.nodes()` to handle the multiple `<SubTask>` entries you might have.

Try this:

```
SELECT
    submitTime.value('(Project/ProjectId)[1]', 'int') ,
    submitTime.value('(Project/Task/TaskId)[1]', 'int'),
    subtask.value('(SubTaskId)[1]', 'int'),
    subtask.value('(Hours)[1]', 'int')
FROM
    @SaveTimeDate.nodes('/xmlSubmitTime/submitTime') AS TEMPTABLE(submitTime)
CROSS APPLY
    submitTime.nodes('Project/Task/SubTask') AS XT(subtask)
```

This should return the output you're looking for. You need to get the `/Project/Task/SubTask` nodes as a list of XML sub-fragments, too - and you need to grab the `SubTaskId` and `Hours` values from those child nodes to get all the information

Comment: @user3791199: If you feel this answer helped you solve your problem, then please [**accept this answer**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/153998). This will show your appreciation for the people who *spent their own time to help you*.